# Javascript Uncaught TypeError on one page, but works on the next?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Working on a wordpress site and adding a sliding marker when hovering over a nav menu bar.

The website - http://avuedesigns.com/iaq

In the chrome Developer tools, it is showing this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined script.js:242
(anonymous function) script.js:242
v.event.special.(anonymous function).handle jquery.js:2
v.event.dispatch jquery.js:2
o.handle.u
```

The only page the menu works on is the cart page, and my account's. I am assuming it might have to be a conflict with library's, because of a similar situation I had a few days ago. But I do not know the proper way of solving this issue and wish to find guidance so I do not waste anyone's time with simple questions.

I do know that the marker is off on the working page, had no time to adjust it, wanted to get it working first =P.

Thanks for your time and wisdom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're using the wrong class to get the position value for `#slidingArrow` in script.js @ Line 231:

```
activeItem = menuList.find('.current_page_item, .current_page_ancestor, .current_page_parent');
```

I think you would be better suited to switch out `.current_page_item` for `.current-menu-item`. The `.current_page_item` class did not appear to be populating on all the pages so the `#slidingArrow` div element was unable to get any positioning information.

In script.js here are the changes I made to `menuSlidingArrow()`:

```
function menuSlidingArrow() {

    if(!($j('html').hasClass('oldie'))) {

        var mainmenu    = $j('.menu-content'),
            arrow       = $j('#slidingArrow'),
            menuList    = mainmenu.find('ul.menu'),
            activeItem  = menuList.find('.current-menu-item, .current_page_ancestor, .current_page_parent'); //remove .current_page_item

        $j(window).load(function() {
            arrow.css({ 'left':(activeItem.position().left + ((activeItem.outerWidth() - 48)/2) ) -6});
            arrow.fadeIn('slow');
        });

        menuList.children().hover(function(){
            arrow.animate({ 'left':($j(this).position().left + (($j(this).outerWidth() - 48)/2) ) -6},
                { queue: false, easing: 'easeOutQuad', duration: 250 });
        },function(){
            arrow.animate({ 'left':(activeItem.position().left + ((activeItem.outerWidth() - 48)/2) ) -6},
                { queue: false, easing: 'easeOutQuad', duration: 250 });
        });
    }

}
```

I also needed the following CSS to get it to work:

```
#menu-main-menu {
    margin-left:68px;
}
#menu-item-8197 a { /* hide home navigation item */
    color:#fff;
}
#slidingArrow {
    margin-left:77px;
}
```

Lastly, be sure you add the 'Home' page to the top navigation. You're going to want to add it as the first item on the navigation.

All in all I changed/added:

- `.current_page_item` changed to `.current-menu-item`
- Added `#slidingArrow { margin-left: 77px; }`, `menu-item-8197 a { color:#fff; }`, `#menu-main-menu { margin-left:68px; }`
- Modified calculations to center `#slidingArrow` under the navigation item
- Added home to the navigation
- Hide home navigation element on navigation

Let me know how this works for you and if you run into any errors I'd be happy to get my answer corrected for you.

Comment: for some reason the front page did not like that at all, and the arror did not show up =(

Comment: this is the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'isArray' of undefined

Comment: On your website add 'Home' to the top navigation bar as the first item. Be sure the page ID of 'Home' matches with the `#menu-item-1897 a` CSS rule. You can copy over the new JS (removed the `$.isArray()`, it actually wasn't necessary). Also the updated CSS is vital to making this function correctly.

One of the reasons it was acting especially strange on the homepage was because the header navigation element did not contain any elements with a class of `.current-menu-item`. Once we add the Homepage to the top navigation that will alleviate this worry.

Comment: Thank you so so much. This did the trick. If you have any more time to spare, could you possible give me some tips on how you debug this and came to a solution. I love to learn and can not just accept the solution as is. If you do not have the time at this moment I do understand, and once again thank you for your time!

Comment: Here's how I came to a solution. The console let us know `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined script.js:242`. Went to script.js @ Line 242. It was trying to get the left property for `var activeItem`. This is how `var activeItem` was declared in your JavaScript: `activeItem = menuList.find('.current_page_item, .current_page_ancestor, .current_page_parent');` Problem here is that `.current_page_item`, `.current_page_ancestor`, and `.current_page_parent` did not exist on the page. This is why I suggested you change over to `.current-page-item`. After this we needed to ..

Comment: Add the 'Home' to the top navigation. After this we simply needed to make CSS adjustments to position the 'Home' item behind your logo and also change the color to `#fff` to match the background. Voila!

Answer (score 0):

This function is returning nothing, so activeItem is defined as an empty array, that's why your code doesn't work, check in you other pages which parameters are you sending to the `menuList.find()` function and see if they're different.

script.js line 231 :

```
activeItem = menuList.find('.current_page_item, .current_page_ancestor, .current_page_parent');
```

Comment: which would be the best way to debug this?